# How to bulk insert flat file have Unicode work with Vietnamese

Tags: sql, sql-server, flat-file, import-from-csv

I have a flat file which I need to import to SQL.

Datatype of table is nvarchar(4000). I also use format file which is xml file.

the problem is the flat file has 'PM vuông' but when I imported to SQL, this is what I get: 'PM vuĂ´ng'.

I also use the collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and also: Vietnamese_CI_AS but it might not work. Does anyone know how to fix it. Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61ZCy.png)

Comment: What is your target database engine?

Comment: @ThangLeQuoc What do you mean database engine ?

Comment: The type of database being used for this importing action, is it MySQL, or Postgres, etc

Comment: I tagged it as `sql-server` as he is using `nvarchar` and says `format file in xml`, it is a feature of BCP command-line tool for SQL Server for importing text files.

Comment: @ThangLeQuoc be sure that your text file is not UTF8 as SQL Server doesn't directly support, convert your text file into a correct collation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.